# Trying to change button text/value in forEach in React JS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, button, dynamic, foreach

I have buttons that are created in a forEach loop, with a '+', cause these buttons are opening a list of Serial Numbers.
Thing is, all these buttons are independants, if I click on one I want it to change text/value to '-'. So firstly I put values in a state, and with a handler with a boolean state, it changed values on click. Problem is, all buttons were changing, that is normal reaction in fact.
I want sibling the button that I'm clicking, and just this one have to change.
So I get it with event.target, but I can't succeed to change it, I'm just clicking and text still's the same.

So here it is *(I cut a little bit of code, to be clearer. And the toggleOpen() si to open all the serials lists in same time. For this one, all's good)* :

### StockTable.tsx

```js
interface Props {
    datas: Array<StockDatas>;
    hideSerial: boolean;
    searchString: string;
}

const StockTable: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ datas, hideSerial, searchString }) => {


    const [open, setOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const toggleOpen = () => setOpen(!open);


    const handleClick = (e: any) => {
        
        const currentButton = e.target;
        if(currentButton.innerText === '+'){
            console.log('Im in')
            currentButton.innerText = '-';
        }
        
    }
 const getLines = () => {
        
        let lines: Array<any> = [];
        if (datas.length === 0) {

                    data.stocks.content.forEach((elem: Status) => {
                        lines.push(
                            <tr key={data.nno + elem.status}>
                                <td>
                                    <button 
                                        className="ButtonHideSerial" 
                                        name={data.nno}
                                        onClick={ (e) => {
                                            toggleOpen();
                                            handleClick(e)
                                        }}
                                    > + </button>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                        
                    })
                }
            })
        
            
        }
        return lines;
    }
```

Comment: when you call handleClick(e) you need to pass the id of stock with the event

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @sodhi-saab !! So now, I get the good button, I retrieve the button, I can console.log the text in, but still can't change the text, I tried with 'textContent, innerText, innerHtml' nothing works and no console error.
I really don't get it

```js
const handleClick = (e: any) => {
        
        const currentButton = document.getElementById(e.target.id);
        if(currentButton.innerText === '+'){
            console.log('Im in')
            currentButton.textContent = '-';
          //currentButton.innerText = '-';
          //currentButton.innerHTML = '-';
        }
        
    }
```